# Web Element sendKeys() adds an extra character no matter what string I pass. How to fix?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am working in with Selenium 3.14 in java to do UI testing on a login page. My code is trying to send values to an input element named password. Which is the field to input a password. Passing in "1111" will output a five digit string into the input field. It was working fine before but now it won't work at all.

`value="1111"
browser.findElement(passwordElement).sendKeys(value);`

My output is some 5 character string. But the length should be 4

Answer (score 1):

```
element.clear()
```

before

```
element.sendKeys()
```